# Janus upgrade important functionality missing after upgrade

Tags: vim, macvim, janus

I just upgraded to the newest Janus and there are alot of things that I miss since December 2011 :(

For example when i entered `:cd` it changed to `:ChangeDirectory` and after changing the directory the nerdtree also updated. The same thing applies for `:e` which changes to `:Edit`

This is not anymore the case with the newest Janus.

Command-T is also not anymore available anymore. What is the easiest way to add Command-T as a plugin?

Greetings from Nepal and Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

**First,** what happens to you is the number one reason why using Janus (and other packages for Vim) is a terrible idea.

Instead of controlling your environment your are almost totally dependent on someone else's desiderata: because Janus's author appears to have decided against some of his previous choices and upgrading Janus is an "all or none" affair you are left in the cold with a Vim you don't understand or are not accustomed to.

You don't have to trust me but I assure you that the *right way* to customize Vim is to start with nothing fancy, do it yourself, little by little, without copying other people's entire vimrcs and try and install the plugins you like by yourself. Because you start from nothing and know what you add you'll never be in that kind of situation.

**Second,** whenever you upgrade something you owe it to yourself to review the changes before actually performing the upgrade. `$ rake` is easy, I must admit, but if you had taken a couple of minutes to look at [Janus's Github page](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) you would have seen that Command-T is not included anymore and replaced by [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim).

**Third,** [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t) is not and has never been a part of Janus. It's a separate project run by someone else that used to be included as a Git submodule. To install it, you need to download it separately and follow [the instructions](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T). Or add it yourself as a submodule.

**Four,** greetings from France, lucky bastard ;).

*EDIT*

To answer your comments…

I went through the TM > Vim transition myself. I started by trying to turn Vim into a TM clone but the whole idea was flawed in so many ways. Many of these flaws apply to Janus as well, IMO.

- You have too many custom "mac-like" mappings that seem to make your life easier because they don't require you to learn new shortcuts. That's cool until you need to use Vim on a remote server via a terminal emulator which actively blocks many `Ctrl-` mappings, doesn't make the difference between `Ctrl+Shift` and `Ctrl` and don't even register the `Cmd` key.

  If your `vimrc` is well organised (and it is, more or less, in Janus) your `<D->` custom mappings won't be activated when not in MacVim but you'll end up with *two* sets of custom mappings to learn and maintain! What if Janus's author decides one day that he prefers `<leader>x` to jump to tab `x` instead of the current `<D-x>`/`<C-x>`? Are you going to unlearn the previous mappings? Are you going to modify Janus's `mappings.vim` to get the old mappings back?

  Why not learn and use Vim's native commands instead? `2gt` is easy and will likely work on every Vim you'll ever come across.

  You grow accustomed and dependent to too many plugins, some of them not doing much more than native commands or even overlaping each other like the current Buffergator and CtrlP.
- Customizing Vim is a great way to learn how to use it. It takes time, maybe, but the win is big.

*ENDEDIT*

Comment: I see your point, but configuring everything myself would probably led me to not using it. Janus has helped me and many others to use vim with settings that make it much easier to learn it and mappings which were aligned to work just as in TextMate. Making all these mappings on your own would be just too much.

You are not totally dependent on other choices, that is why there was a .vimrc.local and now a .vimrc.before/.vimrc.after

Comment: regarding Third: Yes, before the big upgrade Command-T was part of Janus that is why I was using it. Now I am again accustomed to FuzzyFinder and I can see it's benefits before Command-T

Comment: just come over to Pokhara, it's nice and warm here and we are surrounded by moutains and a lake ;)